# Is there any way to upload a file to my private aws s3 bucket from Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3

I have tried multiple packages like "amazon_s3_cognito: ^0.6.0","simple_s3" etc. none
of them are working for private bucket file upload from flutter. Is there any way to upload files without amplify backend?